# Running stored procedure with alive signal because of time out

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with custom table data type like this :

```
CREATE TYPE VALUE_BIGINT AS TABLE (VALUE BIGINT NOT NULL)
```

and this is the stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCalculate (@EmpIds VALUE_BIGINT READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        *, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VALUE)) AS RowIndex
    INTO #Tmp
    FROM @EmpIds

    DECLARE @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    DECLARE @I INT = 1

    WHILE @I <= @RowCount
    BEGIN
        --Executing query(about 2 sec long)
        --!!!SEND Live Signal To C#!!!
        SET @I = @I + 1
    END

    DROP TABLE #Tmp
END
```

I know that I can set infinity timeout for this stored procedure to ensure execute success but I don't want do this! Because of network issue. I want to send alive signal or something like this to sure my stored procedure is still running ("`SqlCommand` be patient don't throw timeout exception")

I know we can do this because SQL Server Management Studio can do this! But how?

Comment: " i know we can do this because SQL Management studio can do this! but how?" - SQL Management studio  has infinite timeout. rethink your design and speed up underlying query. Classic XY problem.....

Comment: @MitchWheat : if we write waitfor delay '00:01:00' and after that stop sql service management can understand that and show error to us, also think query that i wrote is Optimized and 1sec long but when i pass more record to sp again error came back!

Comment: you are attempting to solve the wrong problem.....